# A few questions about working with writable Xlinks in Plastic SCM

Tags: plasticscm

I need some information about working with writable Xlinks.

I have two projects, let's call them **Project A** and **Project B**.

Each project has its own repository: **Repo A**; and **Repo B**.  Each project also has its own workspace: **C:\Projects\Project A**; and **C:\Projects\Project B**;

**Project B** references **Project A**, so I created a writable Xlink in **Project B's** workspace to reference **Project A**, setting the 'XLink target changeset' to the last changeset in **Project A**.  I did my check-ins and updates and the code from **Project A** now appears in a folder under **Project B**: **C:\Projects\Project B\Project A**.  All that apprears to be working as expected.

However, when I made changes to **Project A** (in **Project A's** workspace) and checked them in, the Xlink did not change.  I then edited the Xlink and updated the 'Xlink target changeset' to the new last changeset in **Project A**, did my check-in and update, and then it pulled the latest code from **Project A** into the folder under **Project B**.

So I have a few of questions:

What do I have to do to get the Xlink to show as changed?

When working on **Project A**, should I be working in **Project A's** workspace (**C:\Projects\Project A**), or should I be working on the **Project A** code in **Project B's** workspace (**C:\Projects\Project B\Project A**)?

Assuming that I *am* making changes to **Project A** in **Project B's** workspace, do I even need a workspace for **Project A**?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xlink is an static object, so right now, it's not able to track newest changes in the target changeset branch (**Project A**).

You need to evolve the **Project A** repository using the **Project B** repository. So, in your case, you need to work through **Project B** to make changes under **Project A**.

As you may know if you create a new branch in **Project B** and then you perform changes under `C:\Projects\Project B\Project A` a new branch will be automatically created in the **Project A** repository to hold the changes, and even more, if you merge the **Project B** task branch the **Project A** task branch will be also automatically merged.

Here you have a blog post talking about your scenario: http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-link-repositories-using-xlinks.html

Comment: Thanks, @MrCatacroquer.  That was the information I was looking for.  I still have one slight issue, though: after creating the Xlink (basically following the same steps as described in the blog post) I've had trouble getting the files from the remote repository to show up.  I've tried the `Update` and `Update forced` commands, neither of which worked.  The files _do_ eventually appear after switching the workspace to a previous change set and back a couple of times.  Any idea what would cause this, or what information you would need from me to diagnosis the issue?

Comment: Well, a regular update operation should download everything from the xlinked repository, but if it's not doing it don't hesitate to contact the Plastic SCM support crew at plasticscm.net